# Is there a way to remove all letters from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I have a list of titles with combined dates and descriptions, but I have to reduce this to just a list of dates. Some examples of these titles are stuff like this:

> 1/16 Stories of Time

> 5/18 Cock'a'doodle'do

However, some people are really bad at typing and have forgotten the spaces between the dates and the rest of the title. I need to remove everything except for numbers and the slashes between them. Using any method, but preferably regex, is there a simple way to do this? For the record, I do understand how to split and recompile the list for any method that would work on a single string.

Comment: If people always write the date that way, just do a `findall` on `r"\d+/\d+"`.  You can use `{1,2}` instead of the `+` to only grab things with one or two digits.

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^\d/]', '', string)` will remove everything that isn't a digit or `/`

Comment: @Barmar thats bs if i have something like /2234, 22222/, ///////, 2424422442, do you suppose this to be valid input?

Comment: @muzzletov That's not what the question asked. If he needs to handle other input, the question needs to say that.

Comment: @Barmar, its not about you being right but OP getting the right answer. if youre right in your mind that doesnt even help you. :D

Comment: @muzzletov True. If they ask the wrong question, they'll often get the wrong answer. I will usually ask for clarifications like this before posting a real answer. I'm not as careful about comments.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this backwards. If you want to extract the date at the start of a line, do that instead of trying to get rid of everything else.

You can use a regex like this: `^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}` which means:

- `^` start of line
- `\d` digit

  - `{1,2}` repeated one or two times

For example:

```
import re

lines = [
    '1/16 Stories of Time',
    "5/18 Cock'a'doodle'do",
    '6/22Bible']

for line in lines:
    match = re.match(r'^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}', line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(0))
```

Output:

```
1/16
5/18
6/22
```

(Note that `re.match` always starts matching from the start of the string, so the `^` is redundant here.)

This is more rigorous against titles containing numbers and slashes, like say, `4/5 The 39 Steps / The Thirty-Nine Steps` -> `4/5`.

However, you'll have a problem if someone forgot the space for a title starts with a number, like say, `7/8100 Years of Solitude` -> `7/81`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `import string` to get easy access to a string of all digits, add the slash to it, and then compare your date string against that to drop any character from the date string that's not in there:

```
import string
string.digits += "/"
for character in date_string:
    if not character in string.digits:
        date_string = date_string.replace(character, "")
```

This will convert the date_string `5/18 Cock'a'doodle'do` to just `5/18` without using regex at all.

Comment: What about `'5/18 And another other 5 words with 1 number in it.'`?  It will fail in this case. Regex would be more robust.

Answer (score -1):

Barmar on the comment of the original question had the best answer. To remove all but the numbers and a slash from the string you can use the one line of code,

> string = re.sub(r'[^\d/]', '', string)

This removes all letters but ignores slashes. Thank you Barmar, if you want to post this as an answer I can take this down and flag that instead.

Answer (score -2):

```
string = "rk3k3rr3kk____"
print("".join([letter for letter in string if not letter.isalpha()]))
```

But this is what you actually want, since your data seems to always have be a specific kind of format:
`string.split(" ")[0]`
okay,okay,okay ... this is what you want:

```
string[:4]
```

for completness sake:

```
string = " 2/24 4/12 333333 effee24/22"

for i, x in enumerate(string):
    if len(string) <= i + 4:
        break
    
    if i > 0 and x != " " and not x.isalpha():
        continue
    
    if not string[i+1].isnumeric():
        continue
    
    if string[i+2] != "/":
        continue
    
    if not string[i+3].isnumeric():
        continue
    
    if not string[i+4].isnumeric():
        continue
    
    if len(string) == i + 6 and string[i+5] != " " and not string[i+5].isalpha():
        continue
    
    print(string[i+1:i+5])
```

Comment: it does what the title says, btw, but not what the text says

Comment: but, here is an example to satisfy what you asked for in the description ```string.split(" ")[0]```

Comment: gosh, one has to read the whole text to get what u want: ```text[:4]```